# Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server database migration for Jira

Tags: postgresql, jira, database-migration, azure-postgresql

I am trying to migrate my Jira database which I am running on my Azure PostgreSQL single server to the new flexible server. When doing the migration I am encountering the following error:

```
pgcopydb failed with the errors: 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 
ERROR pgsql.c:1892 Postgres result status is PGRES_FATAL_ERROR 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 ERROR pgsql.c:1543 [SOURCE] 
ERROR: relation "jira.ao_0201f0_stats_event_param_id_seq" does not exist 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 
ERROR pgsql.c:1548 SQL query: select has_sequence_privilege($1, $2); 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 
ERROR pgsql.c:1549 SQL params: 'jira.AO_0201F0_STATS_EVENT_PARAM_ID_seq', 'select' 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 
ERROR pgsql.c:1303 Failed to query privileges for sequence "jira.AO_0201F0_STATS_EVENT_PARAM_ID_seq" 2023-06-23 08:07:11 32 
ERROR cli_clone_follow.c:433 Failed to clone source database, see above for details 2023-06-23 08:07:11 28 
ERROR cli_clone_follow.c:696 clone process 32 has terminated [6]
```

I have the mentioned sequences inside my database, but in uppercase. Why is this issue happening? I did the same migration on another environment and no issues happened.

Tried to created lowercase sequences but I didn't like the idea of that. Are there other ways.